# jQuery: How can I improve this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have this tap event in an iOS app that I'm developing with PhoneGap. When I click on the left arrow, it finds the desired content and retrieves it from a JSON file. It then displays those results on the screen.

How can I improve this? There's a bit of lag... I know that some of the lag is attributed to the 300ms delay (which fastclick.js and other libraries could resolve), but what else can I do to restructure this code and make it more snappy? I need it to respond quickly.
Thanks!

```
// PREVIOUS DAYS
    $('.left-arrow').on("tap", function() {
        dateArrayIndex--;
        todaysDate = morehShiur[dateArrayIndex]['date'];
        todaysContent = morehShiur[dateArrayIndex]['description'];
        $('.date').text(todaysDate);
        var path = window.location.href.replace('index.html', '');
        $.getJSON(path + "data/heb-text/" + todaysContent, function(data) {
            $('.title').empty();
            $('ol').empty();
            $('.title').append(data['title']);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.content.length; ++i) {
                $('ol').append('<li>' + data.content[i]['content'] + '</li>');
            }
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
        });
    });
```

Comment: The lag probably is in the ajax call. Each tap is a request. What you can do is make some sort of cache/pre-fetching of the data.

Comment: If this code is working then this question is probably better asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TravisJ: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments that your lag is likely related to doing an ajax call. However, there are a few things you can do to this code that will potentially improve things.

- You can scope or cache your selectors like `$('.date')`. DOM lookups are expensive.
- You can select multiple things using a `,` so your empty becomes: `$('.title, ol').empty()`
- You can build HTML once in memory and **then** append to the DOM rather than appending with each iteration in your for loop.

As an example of the last point:

```
var $liArray = $('<div/>');
for (var i = 0; i < data.content.length; ++i) {
  $liArray.append('<li>Hello</li>');
}
$("ol").append($liArray);
```

Comment: @shmuli - Does that make more sense?

Comment: I guess you're building up the content while it's still in memory, and then appending it to the DOM **ONCE** rather than going back and forth to the DOM on each loop?

Comment: The browser has to re-render parts of the page every time you modify the DOM so yes the idea is that you're only interacting with the DOM one time. As for map/for the vanilla version is considerably faster. I'm removing that from the answer. Thanks for forcing me to check on that.
http://jsperf.com/jquery-map-vs-standard-array-map

Comment: Thanks for your help here! I'm marking your response as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache the server data at the client to avoid repeated server calls. 
Also you can pre-fetch 3 days of data(current date, previous date and next date). So the user does not see the delay for the current date. But in the background you are fetching data for other days.

You can try libraries like http://amplifyjs.com/ for request caching.